# Place a dynamic marker on AGM maps

Tags: angular, typescript, maps

I used Angular Google Maps (AGM) to get longitude and latitude of chosen location and it worked successfully , as it sends a correct data . i want to put marker in retrieved location when i retrieve this data [Two way Binding]

component.html:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="GPSLatitude" [longitude]="GPSLongitude"  (mapClick)="placeMarker($event)">
    <agm-marker [latitude]="GPSLatitude" [longitude]="GPSLongitude"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.GPSLatitude = 29.98110768446724; //As Default Value
  this.GPSLongitude= 31.268634796142578; //As Default Value

  this.myform = new FormGroup({
    GPSLatitude: new FormControl(this.GPSLatitude),
    GPSLongitude: new FormControl(this.GPSLongitude),
  })

showData(BranchID){
  this.RData = this.branches.find(n => n.BranchID === BranchID);
  console.log(this.RData) // it retrieve object with saved location correctly
  this.GPSLatitude = this.RData.GPSLatitude;
  this.GPSLongitude = this.RData.GPSLongitude;

  this.myform.controls['GPSLatitude'].setValue(this.RData.GPSLongitude);
  this.myform.controls['GPSLongitude'].setValue(this.RData.GPSLongitude)
  console.log(this.GPSLongitude) // it retrieve right longitude as i saved before in obj
 }

placeMarker($event){
  this.GPSLatitude = $event.coords.lat;
  this.GPSLongitude =  $event.coords.lng;
}
```

when i cal showData marker still in it's default value .. how can i change the location of marker as retrieved longitude and latitude

Comment: have u got an answer to this?